# Check if table exists using mybatis and Oracle

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis to create an Oracle table called `User`. If the table exists, it will just display the message `Table User already exists` and won't create it again. Currently I'm using this method.

```
public void createTable() {
    try {
        userMapper.createTable();
    } catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
        log.error("Table User already exists");
    }
}
```

It kind of works by now. But I don't think this is a reliable way to do it, because there are multiple ways to trigger `BadSqlGrammarException`.

Apart from catching the exception, I also thought about checking if table exists or not first, but I cannot find a way to achieve it without calling a procedure.

Is there an elegant and correct way to check if table exists using Mybatis and Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to achieve this.

Add the following text to mybatis mapper file

```
<select id="checkTableExists" resultType="int">
<![CDATA[
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'CHECKSTATUS_LOG'
]]>
</select>
```

Declare it in the mapper class(along with `createTable` method, of course)

```
public interface CheckStatusLogMapper {
    void createTable();
    int checkTableExists();
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
public void createTableIfNotExists) {
    boolean b = checkTableExists();
    if(!b) {
        checkStatusLogMapper.createTable();
    }
}
```